# RegEx not matching all required chars. What did I do wrong?

Tags: php, regex

I want to allow inputs like _X_C or _X_X_X with the following regex:

```
^(\_X\_C|\_X\_L|\_L?)((\_X){0,3})$
```

The following should be allowed only once:

- _X_C
- _X_L
- _L

or ...

- _X_X_X (0 to threetimes)

The only thing that does not work is the allowance of "_X_X_X" or even "_X"

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Did my answer below solve the problem?

Comment: Yesterday I did comment your answer. Somehow the comment disappeared.

However: yes, thank you so much! Your answer did solve my problem(s)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```php
^(?:_X_C|_X_L|_L?|(?:_X){0,3})$
^(?:_X_[CL]|_L?|(?:_X){0,3})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bjntFt/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `_X_[CL]|` - `_X_` and then `C` or `L`, or
  - `_L?|` - a `_` and then an optional `L`, or
  - `(?:_X){0,3}` - zero, one, two or three occurrences of `_X` substring
- `)` - end of the group
- `$` - end of string.